# При установке visual studio 2015 на ssd диск загружается на 100% и все зависает?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

Доброго времени суток, вчера купил себе ssd диск(adata sp550 240 GB ), установил Windows 10 без каких-либо проблем, установил видео драйвер - все хорошо, а как только запустил установку vs2015 из онлайн установщика,примерно на 30% все зависло и перестало быть кликабельным, я подождал минут 30 - ситуация не изменилась, принудительно выключил компьютер нажатием и удержанием на кнопку включения, после пришлось восстанавливать Windows, я ее восстановил удалив все пользовательские файлы тем самым получив чистую ось. Я решил что проблема может быть в обновлениях, я оставил его на ночь, на всякий случай, утром установил все обновления, установил себе хром, диск периодически забивался,но не зависал, опять таки при установке vs2015 все зависло и на момент написания вопроса висит почти час. В чем может быть проблема, может кто-нибудь сталкивался ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, был плохой образ виндоус.